# I cannot enter my password in the terminal - can't install packages

Tags: command-line, password, sudo, authentication

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Nothing shows up on the screen when I type my password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/112069/nothing-shows-up-on-the-screen-when-i-type-my-password)

- I can open a terminal (Ctrl-Alt-T)
- I can copy or type in the following:

  ```
  sudo wget http://www.medibuntu.org/sources.list.d/oneiric.list -O /etc/apt/sources.list.d/medibuntu.list
  ```
- When prompted for password, I cannot enter anything via keyboard.

Any clues?

Answer (score 8):

More than likely, you can enter your password just fine.  The password does not show up in the terminal when you type it, but that is for security reasons.  Just try typing your password out, and hitting enter.  If your password was entered correctly, the action will continue.  If your password was spelled wrong, it will prompt you to enter it again.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. Of course - it's 10 years since I used a unix box... I was typing blind and finding the command rejected so assumed sth was badly wrong. Seems OK now.

Answer (score 4):

Your password will not be echoed to you when you type - you won't even see `*` - just keep tying and press Return when done - your password is most likely being accepted even though you can't see it :)

Comment: See remarks in response to the above. Thx for your help.