# Terminal window not showing password

Tags: command-line, keyboard, password

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Nothing shows up on the screen when I type my password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/112069/nothing-shows-up-on-the-screen-when-i-type-my-password)

When I open a terminal and it asks for my password I can't type in the PW because the keyboard wont react. It works fine anyother time. Just not then.