# sudo in the Terminal seems not to accept password input

Tags: command-line, password, sudo, authentication

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Nothing shows up on the screen when I type my password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/112069/nothing-shows-up-on-the-screen-when-i-type-my-password)

I upgraded to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and was trying to update software with `sudo apt-get ...`. In the Terminal I am asked for my password but it will not accept any form of input. I've tried typing it in, as well as pasting from the clipboard. What should I do?

Comment: Remember that the terminal WONT echo back asterisks for characters in your password. If you know that and you are completely sure that you put in the right password (for a user with sudo priviledge): try a different terminal (perhaps the one at `alt+ctrl+F1`). You can also use GUI sudo (for example `gksudo`). As soon as your system is up to date check if the problem is still present and if it is -- report a bug.

Answer (score 3):

When you use the Terminal and you need to enter your password, it will not show on the screen at all, this is normal practice.

Answer (score 1):

When the terminal asks for your password just type clear without caps lock on. Note that the password is the same as our Ubuntu login password.