# When I run sudo lshw in terminal, it asks for my administrator password, but it won't accept keyboard input when I try to type?

Tags: 12.04, command-line, keyboard, sudo, input

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Nothing shows up on the screen when I type my password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/112069/nothing-shows-up-on-the-screen-when-i-type-my-password)

I have been trying to run [sudo lshw] but it asks [password for grace: [] ]
So when I try to type my password, it doesn't even come up with any letters, asterisks not does the [] move. I typed in my password as normal despite this and pressed [enter] but it just said,

[Sorry, try again. 
           Enter password for grace: [] ]

But I can't type it in?! Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

That's normal behaviour of sudo. Sudo will never give any feedback on the user's input, except for the cursor not blinking while you are typing.

Comment: when something is flagged for closure (or voted as it is in this case) adding half or non-answers just breaks the redirection if the question is closed

Comment: Please delete this answer for the greater good of the community (See aking1012's comment above for why).

Comment: So how can I if tell a question has been flagged for closure? I don't see a sign anywhere. This site is confusing.

Comment: @Cumulus007 You probably couldn't have, because there were probably no close votes when you were composing your answer. Your answer was posted *very shortly* after we close-voted.

Comment: Alright, I will be more vigilant from now on. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @Cumulus007 As you use the site more, you may get a sense of when a question looks like something that's been asked before, and search to find out where (and comment, or, once you have enough reputation to vote-to-close, do that). But I don't think you did anything wrong here. In my opinion, *aking1012* didn't realize that your answer and the first close vote happened at almost exactly the same time. And *izx* didn't realize your answer actually says something none of the others do (and thus should either be merged, or manually deleted here and posted in the master). I think you're doing fine.

Comment: @Cumulus007: I see that now, based on Eliah's comment. Did a dummy edit to your answer just to remove my downvote. We'll try to have this merged with the main question.