# How to make password show asterisks as I type it when running `sudo` command?

Tags: command-line, sudo

Is it possible to make the password visible as asterisks (or any other character) on using `sudo` command?

Currently, it does not display anything, thus making it difficult to count the number of keystrokes pressed..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Open your terminal and edit `/etc/sudoers.tmp` file with:

```
sudo visudo
```

Modify the following line:

```
Defaults env_reset
```

to:

```
Defaults env_reset,pwfeedback
```

Save and exit.
Restart your terminal and now, when you run a command with `sudo`, you should get visual feedback when you type in your password.

Credit goes to: [Make Password Asterisks Visible in Your Mac or Linux Terminal](http://lifehacker.com/make-password-asterisks-visible-in-your-linux-terminal-1183533223)

Answer (score 0):

While there is no configuration nor parameter option to do that directly with in the terminal sudo, you could theoretically accomplish something similar to what you need.

First you will need to set the environment variable

```
export SUDO_ASKPASS=/usr/bin/ssh-askpass
```

Then you would run your command with `-A` option, for example

```
sudo -A ls
```

This will give you a graphical prompt.

In theory you could write your own programme rather than using ssh-askpath, your code needs to display the prompt as it is given in the argv[1], read user's password (displaying stars, circles, or anything else you fancy), and then display it to stdout. Do not worry about displaying it, since sudo will not allow this password to ever be seen, it will intercept such display.

Comment: Oh, i guess i was wrong, there is a way to do stars directly, as pointed by rajagenupula, i stand corrected.