# How can I see my password on the terminal?

Tags: sudo, password

I can't see my password on the command line and even though I am sure that I enter my password correctly, sudo doesn't accept. How can I see my password on the terminal? Is there any way to change it?

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/q/387757/380067

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just confirming that you typed it correctly, type it into the U/N space instead of your username to see what characters are being typed.

Answer (score 2):

1. type it into gedit and copy/paste it into the password field.
2. [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password)

Answer (score 2):

To help you enter your password correctly there is: [How can I make stars appear when I type sudo password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/860766/how-can-i-make-stars-appear-when-i-type-sudo-password)

To summarize the answer there, you need to configure it using:

```
sudo visudo
```

Locate the line containing `env_reset` and add the parameter `, pwfeedback` behind it.

See the link for full instructions.

Comment: `This **** only sh*w aster***s inst**d of char*****s.` At least you can determine whether the length matches.

Comment: @PerlDuck Yes it's for keyboards that lack tactile feedback and answers the question: *"Did I hit that key properly or not?"*. N*ce w*y of wr*ting y*ur c*mment BTW :)