# Hide terminal password as typing

Tags: command-line, 16.04

I am using Ubuntu 16.04

Whenever I use sudo and have to type in my password, the password shows in the terminal screen as I type, only hiding the first character. For example, if my password were "password", as I type the password in the terminal, it would show: $ assword (only hiding the character "p")

I want to hide all the characters as I type (I don't need Ubuntu to show asterisks instead, I want it to show exactly nothing)

How do I achieve that?

For those who think my question is a possible duplicate of another question on "how to make terminal password visible", I want to clarify that it's not the same. It's simply the opposite, and the answers in the other post did not help me solve my problem.

Comment: What you are asking for is normal functionality for sudo. Have you, by any chance, been playing with stty commands or similar in .profile or .bashrc ?

Comment: I notice that in the beginning when I just finished installing Ubuntu, that's how it was. But now it's not applying that default behavior anymore. Maybe it's like you said - that I have messed something up. But I don't remember anything in particular...

Comment: Check `history` for previously used commands to see if there is one that would suggest you edited it into some file. But bashrc and profile would be my first idea too. Did it also happen when you start another shell?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make \`sudo\` command password to visible?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/387757/how-to-make-sudo-command-password-to-visible)

Comment: @Rinzwind yes. It happens in all terminals I run. Also, this has been going for over a week now, so I don't think history would help... But if it was the bashrc and profile, how do I re-modify it?

Comment: @Thomas I saw that one before posting - it's different. They were asking for how to make the password visible, I am wondering how to make it invisible.

Comment: Are you sure you're actually running `sudo`? What is the output of i) `type sudo` and ii) `file $(which sudo)`?  Does it work after you enter your password? You say it shows `$ assword`, why is there a `$` there? That's the default prompt and that's not where you're supposed to be entering the password.

Comment: @terdon yes I am sure I was using sudo. By the way, the output of `type sudo` is `sudo is hashed (/usr/bin/sudo)` and `file $(which sudo)` is `/usr/bin/sudo:  setuid ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=25655e47e5bb20d821269acb65931a5c5d669164, stripped`. It worked after I input my password. I'm sorry for the confusion. I just want to quickly illustrate my main point so I said it showed `$ assword`. It actually showed up like this `[sudo] password for myusername:   assword`

Answer (score 4):

Check the `/etc/sudoers.d` folder if `pwfeedback` file is present. If it is, remove it.

Also check [this link](https://askubuntu.com/a/387764).