# How do i put my password in to terminal?

Tags: command-line

How do i figure out/input my password into terminal? I just started using Ubuntu, and I want to get Netflix on it. When I put in the command line for that, it asks for my password,but I am unable to enter it. What can I do to enter it?

Comment: Just enterit and press enter.

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't type anything i do.

Comment: you can't see what you type when you write your password, that is normal.

Comment: You think it doesn't type. It types but will not show anything (no asterisks or anything). This is the default for security reasons. Type your password carefully and press ENTER

Comment: In Ubuntu terminal nothing seems to be happening when you enter password. This is by design. Type the password even if nothing gets typed in the terminal. Then hit enter. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/175624/what-would-be-the-concept-behind-the-password-not-being-echoed-on-cli

Comment: Is it the same password as my login? or is it a different one?

Comment: yes it's the same.

Comment: try this for to make the sudo password visible http://askubuntu.com/questions/387757/how-to-make-sudo-command-password-to-visible

Comment: That didn't work...

Comment: same as admin login account or root user account.

Answer (score 3):

You are entering it, it just does not appear to change as the password is hidden for security reasons. Not even asterisks appear

For example, here is my 20+ character long password:
[image]

:-)

Answer (score 1):

> **What's the Issue?**
>
> A lot of new users are thrown off by an inconsistency in the Ubuntu interface. When you enter a password in
> the GUI (graphical user interface, where you point and click), there
> is visual feedback—a dot or an asterisk for every character you type.
> When you enter your password in the terminal, the terminal doesn't
> seem to "accept" your password because it doesn't offer any visual
> feedback for the characters you enter.
>
> **How do I solve the "problem"?**
>
> Your password is being accepted in the terminal. You just aren't getting any visual feedback. Go ahead
> and type your password and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> afterwards. If you typed your
> password correctly, there should be no problems.

[Source](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/passwordinterminal)

Though I agree with the following comment from [bodhi.zazen](https://askubuntu.com/users/35795/bodhi-zazen)

> It is not "an inconsistency in the Ubuntu interface", as far as I
> know, this is the default behavior of both sudo and su on all distros.
> It is unfamiliar to new users perhaps, but not an inconsistency.

Comment: It is working :)

Comment: It is not "an inconsistency in the Ubuntu interface", as far as I know, this is the default behavior of both sudo and su on all distros. It is unfamiliar to new users perhaps, but not an inconsistency.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen you are correct, but I quoted the exact content from the page (source), I think I couldn't change this content. I will add your comment in the answer :-)

Comment: The inconsistency is that (some/many/most) GUIs give visual feedback - there has never been one in CLI :-))