# How do I get past a 'frozen' terminal with a sudo password prompt?

Tags: command-line, sudo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Nothing shows up in the terminal when I type my password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/112069/nothing-shows-up-in-the-terminal-when-i-type-my-password)

When running the Terminal and asked for password the terminal freezes - cannot type in or paste. What is the fix?

```
[sudo] password for david:
```

And there I am stuck

Comment: Are you sure you are stuck, the `terminal` does not display the password, nor does it show `*` in place of characters you type? Press enter after you have typed your password to confirm you are stuck.

Comment: Enter your password, press enter, nothing happens? Control+C should break it, does that happen? Are you sure its frozen?

Comment: Control+C clears the "freeze" but I can still not complete any code that requires the password - Just a white flashing box after the :

Comment: Do you have a password for your user or do you just use a blank one?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/q/112069/44179

Comment: It appears you may simply not have been typing in your whole password before pressing enter. When you type in your password, *ignoring that nothing seems to be happening while you do so*, and then after typing in the whole password press Enter, what happens? Is that what you've been doing? (If so, see [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/249209/22949).) Or when you're told to "try again" is that after pressing enter *without* first putting in your whole password? Unless you can provide more information, we should probably go ahead and close this as a duplicate, as @Seth suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Try typing in the password or right clicking to paste the password. Be sure to right click only once to paste. the cursor won't move but the password will be there, then just press enter to logon.

does that help?

Comment: I'm afraid not get message Sorry, try again.  I have no problems if I am just asked to authenticate but cannot run terminal if password required.

Comment: @Mad_Dave, the message "Sorry, try again" appears when the password you have typed is not what you provided while installing Ubuntu or after you have changed in your "Accounts". Do you correctly remember your password? If not, you can try recovery options: http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password, but first confirm you are typing your correct password where it asks you to, though you won't be able to see the password you are typing for security reasons.

Comment: Password is fine as I use it when asked to authenicate when adding software. White box just flashes at me and does not move. If it does accept the enter I get the Sorry try again message

Comment: @Mad_Dave From your comments you appear to have a different question. I suggest to ask a new one or search for similar ones to "Password is correct, but sudo does not accept it and says 'try again'". It has nothing to do with your terminal, but rather with `sudo`.

Comment: @EliahKagan From the report that JamesR404 can right-click (only) to paste, he's using a completely different Terminal, maybe even PuTTY. The confusion started when this answer seemed not to match the situation of OP. I sort-of-answered the question in a comment here. I believe there's something you're missing: that the cursor isn't moving while typing the password.