# Graphical authentication works; why does sudo say my password is wrong?

Tags: password, sudo, root, authentication

I'm trying to install a theme, and when I enter the command `sudo cp -r $HOME/Desktop/Overglossed /usr/share/themes` the terminal asked for my `sudo` password which I entered, however I'm told my password is wrong. What is the problem here? I logged in with the same password, and I don't have cap lock on or anything like that.

This is the first time I have used the terminal, so if this is due to my unfamiliarity with it, please let me know.

I am not always prevented from performing administrative tasks by entering my password. I can install software in the Software Center, for example I installed Chrome (which I have used to work on this question).

Comment: I've posted [an answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/249209/22949) which might solve your problem. If not, what is the *exact* text of the error message you get when `sudo` rejects your password? (Also, you can provide other diagnostic information as explained in that answer.)

Comment: Graphical tools often use PolicyKit, not `sudo`, to verify that the user has certain privileges.

Answer (score 19):

## First... A Probable Workaround

It's likely you can work around this problem until it's solved by using `pkexec` in place of `sudo` when you want to run a command as root. See "**Maybe sudo is Broken**" below for details.

It's not definite that this will work. If not, one of the other solutions or workarounds here might. If not, this will probably still help you gather information about the problem, which you can add to your question.

(People with this problem other than the asker of this question can create a new question with information about what happened when they tried the techniques here.)

---

## The Basics of This Situation

Most of the time, when people report they cannot effectively enter their password for [`sudo`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/sudo.8.html) in a terminal, but can authenticate with it graphically at least some of the time, it is because they don't realize that [no placeholder characters (like `*`) are *supposed* to appear](https://askubuntu.com/questions/112069/nothing-shows-up-in-the-terminal-when-i-type-my-password). Here, it seems that is not the case. **If you entered your password correctly and in full before pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>, there really is some problem.**

To figure out what it is, more information is necessary. Here are some possible causes of `sudo` not accepting the password in the terminal even though you can enter it graphically to install software.

### 1. Maybe the Password is Blank

<sup>*[Suggested by Bruno Pereira.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/234017/how-do-i-get-past-a-frozen-terminal-with-a-sudo-password-prompt#comment290158_234017)*</sup>

If your password is blank, i.e., zero characters long, i.e., you just press <kbd>Enter</kbd> when asked for your password, **change it to something that is not blank.**

It's likely you can change your password in System Settings (since you can perform at least some administrative tasks graphically). If that doesn't work, and you can install software, you can install [gnome-admin-tools [image: Install gnome-admin-tools]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gnome-admin-tools), run `users-admin` (another graphical utility), and change your password that way.

If that doesn't work, try running `pkexec passwd $USER`. (`pkexec` will prompt graphically for your password if a GUI is available and working, even when used to run [CLI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface) commands.)

If that doesn't work, try [any of these methods](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password); if that doesn't work, try [this method](https://askubuntu.com/questions/121698/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-password-using-recovery-mode-requires-me-to-type-the-pass/147023#147023).

### 2. Maybe the Password Contains Weird Characters

If your password contains characters other than the numerals (0-9), capital (A-Z) and lower-case (a-z) letters with no accent marks, and punctuation that appear on a US/English keyboard, change it so it does. If you're using a different locale, then to be safe, you can (temporarily) change your locale as well.

Spaces are ordinarily fine in passwords but as you're having problems it makes sense to try it without them. They're relatively uncommon, so there could be an undiscovered bug triggered by a combination of having a password with spaces in it and some other condition.

### 3. Maybe the Password is Perfectly Ordinary, But Was Stored Wrong

Even if all one or more characters of your password are commonly used, it's still a good idea to change your password to see if it solves the problem. Also, if you change your password and it does not solve your problem, that is another important piece of information.

I've talked to people in this situation, where changing the password fixed the problem, even though there was nothing particularly wrong with or strange about it originally. I suspect that the problem might have to do with how the password is stored, but it could be that the underlying cause is coincidentally corrected by setting the password, or that the situation was (albeit repeatedly by different people) misreported to me, or that I misunderstood.

### 4. Maybe You're Not Typing What You Think You Are

Make sure your keyboard layout is what you think it is when you put in your password.

### 5. Maybe Your Terminal is Misinterpreting Input

Perhaps the password that is being seen is not what you're actually entering. To see if this is the case:

- Enter it in the terminal when not entering your password (don't "run" it, and still *don't tell us what it is*).
- Try it in a different terminal application. You're using Terminal; try xterm. (Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and run `xterm`.)
- Try it on a [virtual console](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_console). Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and see if you can log in. Like when running `sudo`, it's normal for you not to see anything happening as you enter your password. Just type it in and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> when you're done.

  Whether that succeeds or fails, knowing if it worked provides useful information.

  Then try actually running `sudo`.

  *To get back to the GUI, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>.*

### 6. Maybe sudo Works, But Not when Invoked from the Command Line

To check this, run `gksudo xclock`. You'll be prompted graphically for your password, but `sudo` will be used "under the hood."

If that works--that is, if a simple graphical clock application appears--then `sudo` works, but (assuming it also failed when you tried running it in another terminal app and in a virtual console), something is wrong with the way it is taking input from command-line interfaces.

### 7. Maybe CLI Password Authentication is Broken

This could occur if there is a common problem preventing `sudo` and other, different ways of asking for passwords on the command line, from working right.

Run `su $USER -c 'echo Success'`. You'll be prompted for your password. Type it in (again, it's normal to have nothing appear on the screen as you do), press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and see if `Success` appears.

If you were unable to get past authentication there, then the problem affects both terminal-based `sudo` and terminal-based `su`.

### 8. Maybe sudo is Broken

Try running a command with [PolicyKit](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/polkit.8.html): `pkexec echo Success`

A GUI window should come up and ask you for your password; if authentication succeeds, `Success` will appear in the terminal.

***If this works, you have a workaround for the problem: use `pkexec` instead of `sudo`.***

If `sudo` is broken, you might be able to fix it, depending on *what is wrong with `sudo`*:

#### 8.1. Maybe the installation is messed up.

Try reinstalling `sudo` with:

```
pkexec apt-get update && pkexec apt-get --purge --reinstall sudo
```

That may fix a corrupted or misconfigured installation.

#### 8.2. Maybe `sudo` is misconfigured in `/etc/sudoers`.

For misconfigurations relating to unexplained password authentication failures, check the `Defaults` lines in `/etc/sudoers` by running:

```
pkexec grep Defaults /etc/sudoers
```

In Ubuntu the output is normally:

```
Defaults    env_reset
Defaults    secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
```

If you see `rootpw`, `runaspw`, or `targetpw`, this means `sudo` is not necessarily asking for *your* password.

This is particularly likely if you are prompted `[sudo] password for root:` or `[sudo] password for some-other-username` instead of `[sudo] password for your-username`. But it's worth checking for in any case (as it's easy to check).

**Even if you don't see** any of those three `...pw` terms, you still might see something wrong; if your output of `pkexec grep Defaults /etc/sudoers` is not the same as what's shown above, you should look into that (for example, you can include it when you edit your question to provide details about what happened when you tried all these techniques).

If this doesn't reveal anything, take a look at all of `/etc/sudoers`. You can use `pkexec less /etc/sudoers` or open the file in an editor with `pkexec visudo`. If you don't see anything wrong, I recommend still posting the contents of the file in your question.

*If you find a problem in `/etc/sudoers` and know what has to be changed, you can edit it using `pkexec visudo`.*

#### 8.3. Maybe `sudo` is misconfigured in `/etc/sudo.conf`.

Normally on Ubuntu, `/etc/sudo.conf` does not exist. And that is good--it works normally in that situation. If `/etc/sudo.conf` does exist, `sudo` may be configured to work in a radically different way. (Or it might be configured to work exactly the same way, and have nothing to do with your problem. Or anything in between.)

If this file exists, regardless of what's in it, please provide its complete contents.

*If* `/etc/sudo.conf` exists, by default the only uncommented lines (i.e., the only lines that don't start with `#`) are:

```
Plugin sudoers_policy sudoers.so
Plugin sudoers_io sudoers.so
```

This uses the `sudoers` module to control the security policy and interface of `sudo`. If any other module is used, things can be quite different, so that's very relevant information.

#### 8.4. Maybe this is a PAM problem, presenting unusually.

This is kind of a stretch, but maybe `sudo` is configured to use pluggable authentication modules and its PAM configuration has a problem.

- This is a stretch because usually you are not asked to enter a password *at all* when this happens.

To check, run:

```
ls -ld /etc/pam.d
ls -l /etc/pam.d/sudo
cat /etc/pam.d/sudo
```

The text in the terminal should look like this:

```
$ ls -ld /etc/pam.d
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jan 16 01:44 /etc/pam.d
$ ls -l /etc/pam.d/sudo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 239 May 31  2012 /etc/pam.d/sudo
$ cat /etc/pam.d/sudo
#%PAM-1.0

auth       required   pam_env.so readenv=1 user_readenv=0
auth       required   pam_env.so readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale user_readenv=0
@include common-auth
@include common-account
@include common-session-noninteractive
```

If any of the **bold** text differs *at all*, that suggests a problem.

*I got this idea from the upstream `sudo` [troubleshooting page](http://www.sudo.ws/sudo/troubleshooting.html) (but that page does **not** suggest the problem will happen this way).*

### 9. Maybe It's Something Else

Maybe none of the situations covers your problem. Or maybe the problem is that `sudo` is broken, but none of the sub-situations for that apply.

If that's the case, **don't give up!** (Unless you want to.)

Just provide as much more information as possible, including what happened when you tried each technique or diagnostic step. This will likely shed light on the problem.

<sub>***This answer is moved, with slight modification, from [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/234017/22949) (where it didn't really belong, as it's not clear the OP there really has this problem).*** Thanks to [gertvdijk](https://askubuntu.com/users/88802/gertvdijk) for helping me recognize the ambiguity there and suggesting this be posted elsewhere instead. (He is not responsible for any errors here, however.)</sub>

Comment: On "Maybe the Password Contains Weird Characters" -- if your password *starts* with ~ (tilde), then you may need to type ~ twice at the sudo prompt over SSH, because ENTER followed by ~ is a special character sequence for OpenSSH client.

Comment: I have had a consistent problem with this for quite some time on arch.  I fix it *somehow*... and then it returns - at intervals which are just beyond memory for how I fixed it before.  This time it was using `su` (which thankfully still respected my root password), and then using `pacman -S pambase` and fixing PAM.  This is a pretty ridiculous problem to have in 2020.  I may move away from arch because of it.

Comment: for me it was 4/5. My Terminal on Mac was being Janky. Closing and reopening it caused it to paste correctly again. Not sure why this happened.

Answer (score 1):

`sudo` wasn't accepting my password either. It was because I had added

```
auth required pam_tally.so per_user magic_root onerr=fail
```

to the top of `/etc/pam.d/common_auth` in an attempt to create a 10 minute delay after 3 failed password attempts. Removing that one line fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to check `/var/log/auth.log` to see what happens on your `sudo`-ing.

In my case I saw message `sudo: PAM (sudo) illegal module type: i`.

Googling by this message led me to the answer: by some reason when I installed `Unity` on my Ubuntu 18.04 and reconfigured `lightdm`, some code modified file `/etc/pam.d/common-session-noninteractive`. What I really saw in that file was just:

```
i#
# /etc/pam.d/common-session-noninteractive - session-related modules
# common to all non-interactive services
...
```

Yes, just little letter `i` as the first symbol in the file. It's shocking but somehow that happened!

I've rebooted the system in recovery mode (as root), deleted this `i` in file, and now `sudo` works fine!

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you can use `gksudo` instead of `sudo` until the root cause of the issue is resolved.