# been trying for 13 hours to install cinelerra in my ubuntu 12.10 system

Tags: cinelerra

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install Cinelerra 4.4?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/250279/how-do-i-install-cinelerra-4-4)

i have searched the internet all day and evening and tried many different ways  that are offered but still can not get it on my computer. 
  also my terminal does not allow me  to put it there either it claims it needs a password but in my computer files there is none

Comment: How are you installing it? What have you tried. Some more information please. Edit your question for that.

Comment: If I'm guessing correctly [this link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/112069/nothing-shows-up-in-the-terminal-when-i-type-my-password) might answer the OP's issue.