# How do I install Cinelerra 4.4?

Tags: cinelerra

Where I can found a ready-made Cinelerra 4.4 .deb package to install ? Im not an expert to compile everything and resolving all dependencies on my own.

Answer (score 3):

OK, first of all, Cinelerra has 2 versions:

1. Comunity maintained version called cinelerra-cv which the last update was in November 13, 2011 and in the Git repositories 24 Sep 2012. Quite old.
2. Heroine Virtual LTD maintained, which from now I will call cinelerra-hw. Last updated July 9, 2012. Still old.

Ubuntu repositories includes cinelerra-cv package in the repositories while cinelerra-hw seems no were to be found. Or so it seems. In the [launchpad page](https://launchpad.net/~cinelerra-ppa/+archive/ppa) of cinelerra-cv there is a note that reads:

> Experimental builds of Cinelerra based on the upstream Heroine Warrior release (4.4) are available here:
>
> https://launchpad.net/~cinelerra-ppa/+archive/cinelerra-hw

So, we only need to `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cinelerra-ppa/cinelerra-hw` and ready. Please note: **This ppa provides EXPERIMENTAL and therefore untested builds for the upstream release of audio and video editor Cinelerra (v. 4.4).** Any problems with the installation and use goes for your own accord. If you need stability use cinelerra-cv or use the fork lumiera.

Answer (score 0):

In a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>), run these commands to install it from the Cinelerra PPA:

```bash
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cinelerra-ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cinelerra-cv
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't have a .deb for you, but here are some easy to follow instructions for compiling Cinelerra 4.4. There is a good chance that these steps will work for you:

http://n1njahacks.wordpress.com/2013/03/09/installing-cinelerra-4-4-on-ubuntu-12-04/

**EDIT:** Just found this page with a bunch of debs. I have not tried them myself yet.

http://www.deb-multimedia.org/pool/main/c/cinelerra/cinelerra

Comment: I've tried the .deb files and it works, although v4.4 looks like v2.2.

`sudo apt-get remove cinelerra-cv

sudo dpkg -i cinelerra_4.4-dmo1_i386.deb cinelerra-data_4.4-dmo1_all.deb`

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @Braiam: While I'd agree with your comment in general, I do not believe that what you suggest is possible in the current situation. Providing "essential parts of the answer" would require a complete duplication of the information of the first link, since all steps are essential. The 2nd link is a  resource link. The only way to avoid linking would be to upload the files to the forum, which is certainly overkill.

Comment: I believe that it's explained in the link why the contents should be copied here and as you are the writer, I don't think that you have licencing problems with the content. Also remember, that self-promotion is frowned upon in SE networks. If you want assistance about how to proceed you may post a question in [meta].