# Cannot access the /usr/local/bin directory

Tags: command-line

I am installing software via the terminal.

One of the installation steps requires to copy some binary files to the `/usr/local/bin` directory. Using the following command: `cp file1 file2 file3 usr/loca/bin` I get the following message:

**cp: target `usr/local/bin' is not a directory**

I also tried `sudo` but it then asks for the account password. When I try to enter the password, I cannot type anything except press <kbd>enter</kbd>. I removed the password from the account but it keeps asking me for the `sudo` command. What should I do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Your password is being typed normally, it just doesn't show up, see [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/112069/nothing-shows-up-in-the-terminal-when-i-type-my-password). If it isn't the case then there is another issue unfortunately.

Comment: Please post the output of `ls -l /usr/local/bin`. It sounds like you may have created a file in that location instead of a directory.

Comment: Posting this output gives me a "total 0" line. So I guess this directory is empty?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to put something in `/usr/local/bin/`, the command usually is:

```
sudo cp file /usr/local/bin/
```

Depending on the source / permissions of the files, you may additionaly need a chmod:

```
sudo chmod +rx /usr/local/bin/file
```

It's hard to uninstall or update individual packages from `/usr/local/`. If it includes libraries, it might even interfere with official packages. Best not to use it in the first place. If it's a software that's available in Ubuntu's package manager (or one of the PPAs), stop whatever you're doing and use that instead (`sudo apt-get install software`). If there's no ready to use package, the best option is to learn how to build one yourself.

Ubuntu is a very popular distribution. If you Google for something specific, in most cases you'll find someone else has already done the packaging work for you.

Comment: Well, it now says that usr/local/bin is not a directory. I am a total newbie in Ubuntu so forgive me :)

Comment: I did it! Thanks folks for your answers! Some slashes are more than just slashes. ;)