# I can't log into ubuntu server 12.04.2 because it won't let me enter my password on my virtual machine, how can I fix this?

Tags: server, login

It will start to boot up, then it will ask me to enter a user name that I wish to log into, after that it will not let me type my password in.

Comment: Are you sure? See [Nothing shows up in the terminal when I type my password](http://askubuntu.com/questions/112069/nothing-shows-up-in-the-terminal-when-i-type-my-password)

Comment: It still won't log in...

Comment: I re-downloaded it on firefox, and now it works... lol!

Answer (score 0):

You can enter your password, but you don't get any visual feedback.

1. type your login name, press <kbd>enter</kbd>
2. type your password  blind (no cursor, no dots, no stars), press <kbd>enter</kbd>
3. enjoy