# Downloading Netflix Software

Tags: password, netflix

Just started running my computer off of Ubuntu and I'm trying to download some software that will enable me to watch netflix. I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and typed in the commands I found [here](http://www.tutonics.com/2012/11/netflix-for-ubuntu.html#.UgLz83ZDu1I):

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ehoover/compholio && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install netflix-desktop
```

It then asks for my password and has a cursor but will not type anything. Not sure what to do next.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Continue on typing your password. For security measures, you won't see anything when you type, but you **are** actually typing. So just type in the password you use to log in, and hit enter. Read the answers to this question for more information: [Nothing shows up in the terminal when I type my password](http://askubuntu.com/questions/112069/nothing-shows-up-in-the-terminal-when-i-type-my-password) (possible duplicate).