# Wubi overwrites my Ubuntu username to Administrator and ignores my password

Tags: wubi, password, administrator

I know there are ways to get your root access back and change your password, but every time I try a new flavor of Ubuntu (installing using Wubi) my username/password is ignored.

After installing and rebooting, my Ubuntu login screen shows the username "Administrator" (my Windows account name) and no password ever works.

When I try to use *Recovery Mode* to change the password, the keyboard input appears to be blank.

This doesn't happen when running Ubuntu directly from a partition of its own.

Currently running Wubi from a Win7 SP1 AMD 4400+ machine.

Comment: For those voting to close this for being *Off-topic*, please explain why in a comment. It appears to be on topic to me.

Comment: You are apparently talking about the Windows account. If Wubi really did anything to a Windows account that would be a bug in Wubi. So its either about Windows or should be a bug report. Please give additional information so that we can help you to find the best way.

Comment: Well I just found out why my password reset attempts with terminal weren't working and why my keyboard input were unknown characters (not blank): my keyboard layout was set to arabic. But then again I encountered another issue, after setting the keyboard back to english and succesfully changing the password the subsequent reboot shows me a message saying "No root folder found", this time I'm using kubuntu, and btw my Windows is not set to arabic but spanish.

Comment: @guntbert it's not changing the Windows account. Abraham, try to focus on each issue separately (ask another question if you find new problems)

Comment: @bcbc you convinced me :-)

Answer (score 2):

Wubi sets your *Account Name* to the Windows Account you installed under, regardless of the *username* you choose. But under the covers, it is using the *username*.

So, you choose `jim` as your username, but install from your Windows `Administrator` account. This means your home directory will be `/home/jim` and your username `jim` and your Terminal prompt `jim@ubuntu`, but on the account login you will be prompted with `Administrator`. You can change this if you like by going to *User Accounts Settings*.

The reason for this *weird* behaviour is that the designer expected you would install under the account `Jim` and then automatically defaulted the username to `jim`. However, the designer didn't code for the case where the account was `Bob` and you installed as `jim`.

But note that the password is always the one entered when you installed Wubi. Make sure you use the one you had to enter twice, regardless of the account name you're greeted with.

**Note**: when you enter a password in the terminal, it automatically suppresses output for security purposes. It doesn't show any response (e.g. not even `*`'s). You just have to type it and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Read this question for more info: [Nothing shows up in the terminal when I type my password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/112069/nothing-shows-up-in-the-terminal-when-i-type-my-password).

Answer (score 0):

Just a very quick tip. If you can boot into grub, then during Grub, press "e", that will bring up the editor, locate to where it says `ro` and change it to `rw`.

You have to do this everytime you boot.

To make the change permanent, run `gksu gedit /etc/grub.d/10_lupin` after booting (replace gedit with your favourite editor, use `sudo nano /etc/grub.d/10_lupin` if you are in the tty), locate the line which says

```
linux   ${rel_dirname}/${basename} root=${LINUX_HOST_DEVICE} loop=${loop_file_relative} ro ${args}
```

and change the `ro` to `rw`, like this:

```
linux   ${rel_dirname}/${basename} root=${LINUX_HOST_DEVICE} loop=${loop_file_relative} rw ${args}
```

Save the file, and run `sudo update-grub`.

This will solve the problem about the missing root folder.