# Different user-name shown in Terminal versus menu bar

Tags: gnome, wubi, username

[image]

I have a normal Wubi instillation and I did not change the settings. But now I find that user-name in the Terminal is different from user account which appears at the top right corner.

How should I do in order to make the two of them coincide?

Comment: Wubi always sets your *display name* to that of your Windows account when you install, but the *username* will be whatever you choose. See here http://askubuntu.com/questions/344631/wubi-overwrites-my-ubuntu-username-to-administrator-and-ignores-my-password

Comment: I have another Wubi on Vista SP2 that does not have this issue. Each time I create new user account terminal comes up with the same name.

Answer (score 2):

This is because your login username is shown in the terminal, but you can have another display name (usually your real name) for gnome/Unity. If you go to settings-> user accounts, you can change the display name associated with your login.