# Enable password asterisks when run command sudo?

Tags: password, sudo

when I run `sudo` command ,  so when I mess up my password, I have to start over from scratch, is there a trick to enable password 
asterisks so I know how letter I have typed?

Comment: related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/112069/nothing-shows-up-in-the-terminal-when-i-type-my-password

Answer (score 1):

Run the following command in a Terminal:

```
sudo visudo
```

Scroll down to the line that looks like this

```
Defaults        env_reset
```

and change it to this:

```
Defaults        env_reset,pwfeedback
```

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to finish editing, <kbd>Y</kbd> to save changes, and <kbd>Enter</kbd> to exit.