# login, password

Tags: login, password

I managed to get ubuntu installed on the extra hard drive. But I can't log in. it shows my username, then login If I type the username it then takes me to the password. It will not allow me to enter a password.

I guess I need to know what information to type in after login, so it will allow me to type in the password I set up. Or I need to know how to change my user name, and password.

Otherwise, I need to know how to remove ubuntu from the hard drive, and format that hard drive. Still waiting to have somebody explain to me how to download the Live CDs and have them boot so that I can try the programs before installing it or them to the extra hard drive.

Comment: Are you facing with [this problem](http://askubuntu.com/q/112069/147044)?

Answer (score 0):

I always use DBAN to completely erase a hard drive. http://www.dban.org/

You could just reinstall Ubuntu though and it'll erase whatever's on there anyways. Download here http://www.ubuntu.com/download Then use CDburnerXP or imgburn to burn a dvd or use UNETbootin for a USB. You can try Ubuntu without installing from the download link I sent you after you burn it.