# help. not letting me type password and task bar gone

Tags: unity, password, taskbar

My laptop task/menu bar that runs along the bottom of the screen has disappear. I found a useful question and answer that said to press ctrl alt f1 then login in and type unity-reset. So I tried that but it wont let me type my password in. :/ does anyone one know why its doing this? Or any other ways I can get my task/menu bar back. Please Help!!!

Comment: See [Nothing shows up in the terminal when I type my password](http://askubuntu.com/questions/112069/nothing-shows-up-in-the-terminal-when-i-type-my-password)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same thing happen to me, try hovering your mouse at the top bar whilst typing.

(I don't have a permanent fix yet, but I have too little reputation to comment.)