# What is the reasoning behind hiding characters when entering the sudo password?

Tags: password, security

When entering the `sudo` password, the • characters are hidden.

Apparently the • are omitted for better security. They seem secure enough to me, and I don't see why they're not used.

I think I'm missing something here...

Could anyone clarify?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nothing shows up in the terminal when I type my password](http://askubuntu.com/questions/112069/nothing-shows-up-in-the-terminal-when-i-type-my-password)

Comment: (In particular, Takkat's answer)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### It makes the password length harder to know.

If your screen is being monitored, for example, using • placeholders would allow an attacker to dramatically reduce the number of passwords they'd need to try in order to crack your password.

Good passwords are made up of a bank of about 40 characters. So compare the difference between If you have a 10 char password, the difference between checking every password up to yours and just checking those with 10 chars is...

[image]
[image]

I probably don't need to spell it out but **~268 trillion attempts is a significant time saving**. This gets even more significant as the password gets longer.

At the other end of the spectrum —really crappy passwords— if you know a target's family members and pets (thanks Facebook) and you know their password length, you might be in the situation where you only need one or two guesses. Enough to get past something like `fail2ban`.

---

Of course if they can see or hear you entering the password, they'll have a better chance of being able to guess it again, but there you go. That's the theory anyway.

Answer (score 2):

- There is no need to show a * when inputting characters.
- Showing a * gives a hint to anyone watching you type: they then know the amount of characters you typed.

And since is it better to type a wrong password than to have 1 person get to know something about your password (even if it is just the length) not showing a * is the better method.

In case of something that has a fixed length (like the PIN at an ATM) showing a * is not a problem: we all know the length already.

Comment: But, if someone is close enough to you to notice how many • you've entered, they're also close enough to look at your keyboard...

Comment: @DevRobot true sort of. I can type my password very quickly and can use my hands to hide what I am typing. But... it is always best to type a password when no-one is looking anyways ;-)

Answer (score 1):

My reasoning behind this is following: number of "•" characters you enter is very big hint for someone that would like to know/break your password. If the bad guy don't see nothing, your password is more secure.

Possibly there are other reasons but one above is enough for me.

Comment: What type of hint?

Comment: hint about how long is your password

Answer (score 1):

the simplest answer is this question : why to show the password ? if someone knows how many character your password has  , he can make a dictionary with all possible
combination of characters and numbers with the same length of your password. it would be cracked later.