# Archivematica install and sudo commands

Tags: software-installation, sudo

I have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS installed on a Win 7 64-bit machine via VirtualBox 5.0.14. Now I want to install a Ubuntu-based software suite called Archivematica. The instructions begin this way:

Add the archivematica/release PPA to your list of trusted repositories (if add-apt-repositories is not available you must install python-software- properties first):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:archivematica/1.4
```

Firstly, I could not figure out how to add a trusted repository and don't know how to tell whether add-apt-repositories is available.

Secondly, when I enter the first sudo command and try to enter a password when prompted in the terminal window, no characters appear as I type.

Can anyone offer insight into these issues? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The command that adds the repository is

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:archivematica/1.4
```

If the `add-apt-repository` command isn't available on your system, the command won't work, and you will need to run

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
```

and try again. However, there's no harm running those commands even if `add-apt-repository` is already available: `apt-get` will simply report that package `python-software-properties` is already the latest version.

For your other query, see [Nothing shows up in the terminal when I type my password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/112069/nothing-shows-up-in-the-terminal-when-i-type-my-password).