# How to reset my lost admin password on 14.04

Tags: 14.04

I have read online and I can only find the method where you hold <kbd>shift</kbd> just after powering on the system.

I have followed instructions and I have done them.
Hut when it tells me to type in a `NEW UNIX PASSWORD` it doesn't let me type in anything.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

That is a security feature, and is **by design**.

It doesn't show you anything, but it will work. Simply hit <kbd>enter</kbd> after typing a new password.

This is a dupe of [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/112069/nothing-shows-up-in-the-terminal-when-i-type-my-password) BTW.