# I can't install anything from Ubuntu 16.04 software center

Tags: 16.04, software-center

[image: screenshot for software center]

When I first opened the software center, everything was okay and I installed something but suddenly I opened it and all I can find is the loading sign or something like this in the screenshot in all categories.

Also when I write something in the terminal window and asks for my password it refuses to type anything in the password line and i don't know what's wrong.

Comment: For your question about your password, see http://askubuntu.com/questions/112069/nothing-shows-up-in-the-terminal-when-i-type-my-password.

Answer (score 0):

Try running all these steps.

Reconfigure unpacked packages

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Fix broken updates

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

Finally, cleanup.

```
sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get clean
```

Also, try to stay away from the `software center` as much as you can, it's very buggy.

Instead try to use `Synaptic (sudo apt-get install synaptic)` which is superior and miles ahead of your current `Software Center`.

If you want an easy point and click Software Manager, try the [Software Boutique](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tZGcAzL4wIk) from `ubuntu-mate`

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-mate-welcome
```