# Unable to login to Ubuntu

Tags: server, login, password

The installation of Ubuntu 14.04.5 server was successfully finished. I type my username and then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. At the next row Ubuntu requests the password but it doesn't take any input except <kbd>Return</kbd> and new row.

I am new on Ubuntu and grateful for any help.

Comment: It's a safety thing that you don't see any input and totally normal. Just type your password and hit enter.

Answer (score 1):

**Don't worry, it is a common and positive behavior.**

Because the output of any software *can* be logged to a permanent storage (like the hard disk) in a format readable by humans, the Linux libraries used by most terminal softwares (in your case the `login` utility with the `PAM` system) have a security feature that hides the passwords from the screen: the password is memorized and - if the software is well made - encrypted in memory when you press `RETURN` **but** even while typing the output does not arrive to the *standard output*.

This both prevents passive screen logging and people near you from catching the password. Have a nice day and remember to type quickly, because anyone can still see your physical keyboard! :-)

---

**Important**: when you see a password field, insert the `root` password **only** if the application is trusted; never publish or save your root password, even if the password field seems secure and does not show any letter.

Comment: Since this is a duplicate question, you should add this answer to the original question, [Nothing shows up in the terminal when I type my password](http://askubuntu.com/q/112069/301745)

Comment: @wjandrea nice idea, I'll clone this answer in case this question gets deleted. ;-)

Comment: If the question gets marked as a duplicate, it won't get deleted, just closed -- unless OP deletes it, that is.

Comment: @wjandrea closed questions may be marked for deletion after some time: we should not lose useful answers, our time is limited and valuable.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that! Thanks!