# Password request issue when entering sudo

Tags: password

I just installed Ubuntu. I wanted to load a software  to allow me to graphically manage media.

1. I got a Terminal.
2. I entered the following: `sudo apt-get install synaptic`
3. The screen prompt demanded a password.
4. I entered my password (not the passphrase)
   result was

   - the system did not seem to be allowing keyboard input At least there was no movement of the  cursor and
   - the system did not recognize my password no matter how many times I entered it.

What am I doing wrong?

Also  I am getting the following when I use the command line

```
System-Product-Name-Invalid-entry-length-16-Fixed-up-to-11:~$
```

What's that?

I tried it again using UXterminal from the Dash this time it recognized my password and gave me a Y/n option and I chose Y

Comment: **(a)** [Nothing shows up in the terminal when I type my password](http://askubuntu.com/questions/112069/nothing-shows-up-in-the-terminal-when-i-type-my-password) **(b)** [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password)

Answer (score 0):

To reset admin password, Boot up the machine, and after the BIOS screen, hold down the left Shift key. You will then be prompted by a menu
-Enter the recovery mode.
-Using the arrow keys scroll down to root and then hit Enter
-At this stage you should have a read-only filesystem. You have to remount it with write permissions:

mount -o rw,remount /

-Now we can set the user's password with the passwd command.

Comment: Thx, but I wasn't trying to reset admin password,  Curious why  my password is accepted when I use UX terminal instead of terminal.

Comment: Sorry about that my bad, why don't you give it a try by reinstalling the terminal maybe it will work then.

Answer (score 0):

The message that you receive in your terminal,

```
System-Product-Name-Invalid-entry-length-16-Fixed-up-to-11:~$
```

It means that your hostname (name of the computer) it's too long.

To change the computer name in Ubuntu, you have to edit two text files, namely **/etc/hostname** and **/etc/hosts**.

After editing the files save them and restart your computer.

- You can also change the computer name by typing this command in terminal:

(change "pc-name" with the name you want for your PC):

```
hostnamectl set-hostname pc-name
```

and then reboot.