# Why can't I type a new password after I've entered the "passwd" command?

Tags: command-line, passwd

I see "enter new UNIX password" but I can't type the new password. No keys work; the only thing I can do is hit the <kbd>enter</kbd> key which takes it a step further to the "Retype new UNIX password" prompt.

What do I do?

Comment: when you type the password, password in invisible in terminal, to protect you from spying eyes, i hope you knew that, and as you're talking about UNIX here, the question should have been posted in http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This is essentially the same issue as [Nothing shows up in the terminal when I type my password](http://askubuntu.com/questions/112069/nothing-shows-up-in-the-terminal-when-i-type-my-password)

Comment: Now it says "authentication token manipulation error"

Comment: Which operating system are you running (distro and version)? In Ubuntu you get superuser permissions via 'sudo' with the command `sudo passwd`

Comment: I'm using version 14.04 on Ubuntu

Comment: Could please take and post a screen shot of what you are trying to do?

Comment: Yes I will do it right now

Comment: I need to wait 20 mins

Answer (score 1):

Although it looks like nothing is happening, your password as you type it is placed character by character by the command in the buffer. It's there. You just can't see it. Just keep typing. This is by design for the purpose of preventing so-called [shoulder surfing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoulder_surfing_(computer_security))—it's when somebody behind your back is looking over your shoulder at what you are typing at the keyboard. So, this is really just a security measure. No need to panic.