# Can't type the password while logging in the Non-Graphical interface (Ctrl+Alt+F3)

Tags: command-line, login, password, gui

I have managed to log before, but now its different. I can type the Login normally and press enter. It asks for the password. But what I type is not displayed on the screen. I have to press enter, what moves it one line down, to start typing the password. Because of that, the password is seem as "incorrect". If I dont press enter it just wont display my password on the screen.

PS: Even trying to type it on "invisible" wont let me in.

PS2: I can log in the Graphical interface without a single digit problem.

What might be causing the problem?

Comment: See [Nothing shows up in the terminal when I type my password](https://askubuntu.com/q/112069/504066). It is about sudo, but the same is true for logging in. No password is shown. Not even stars. Or bullets. Nothing. That is different from the movies where the password is shown in a huge font so everybody in the room can see it.

Comment: Some of that is about `sudo`, but this is true for most password prompts in the terminal (`su`, `passwd`, `pkexec`, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments have already provided the reason for not seeing what you type.

The **Login incorrect** response you are seeing is a result of typing information that doesn't match.

Since you are able to login the GUI without any problems, then you have a correct matching username and password.

To use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F#</kbd> console terminal (a `TTY Console`) you'll have to put the exact information.  The username is case sensitive.

The Username you see on the GUI is a **friendly name** version.  It's almost never the same as your real Username.  While logged in the GUI use this to find the exact spelling of your real username.

- First hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.  From the terminal type in this:

```
$ whoami
```

It will show the exact spelling of your username.  Use that on the **TTY console** and carefully type in the password (which won't echo), then press ENTER.

If the username and password is exact, you will get a login prompt.

Comment: Thank you. I realized I changed my display name and not my username last week; it works just fine now. Thank you again.

Comment: You're welcome.  By the way, you might consider changing the description of your question.  You provided details about the echo which you thought might help.  But the real question was that you can log into the GUI but the TTY login fails.  The better description might leave the question open so that others with a similar issue (which is different from the flagged duplicate) could benefit.