# How to get access to Terminal and Password

Tags: command-line, password, password-recovery

I need to access to Terminal.
Simply clicking on the icon on the desktop does not work.
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> works.
It asks for login and password.
Login is OK.
Password, the system seems not to receive my orders. I type my password, but nothing appears on the screen.
I have UBUNTU 18.04.2 LTS.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, `Ctl+Alt+T` will do.

Comment: Hi, welcome. Can you please explain your issue by adding more details? Are you trying to Login to `TTY2` using `Ctrl+Alt+F2` and when you enter your login it shows login incorrect? In that case type your username exactly as it is and note that the Num-Lock might be disabled. You can find the user name using `whoami` from a Terminal via `Ctrl+Alt+T`

Comment: So you have two problems, the second one (Password is not shown when typing) is a duplicate to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/112069/nothing-shows-up-in-the-terminal-when-i-type-my-password). You might want to edit your question and focus on the first problem (cannot open Terminal from Desktop) and give more details on that. Note that there are similar issues here on that site and you might want to do some research.

Comment: Closely related: [Nothing shows up in the terminal when I type my password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/112069/nothing-shows-up-in-the-terminal-when-i-type-my-password)

Answer (score 6):

No characters being displayed when you enter your password in a shell or TTY is perfectly normal. You can enter your password and press Enter in order to login.

Answer (score 3):

- Switch to tty as you have done: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>
- Input your login: `root`, `user` or whatever your user's name is and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Input your password. Password's input in that TTY is not displayed: there're no circles or asterisks. Since password entered, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Since you've logged in, install another terminal application:

  ```
  sudo apt install lxterminal
  sudo apt install konsole
  ```
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to go back to GUI mode

If new terminal applications do not work, then go back to TTY and copy default configuration files from `/etc/skel` overwriting existing, because of terminal applications failure could be related to user's configuration files misconfiguration:

```
sudo cp -fr /etc/skel/* /home/user/
```

If nothing helps, create a new user, login with it and try again.

You could also have installed `tilix` or `xterm`, so you could try to find them.

Another way of opening terminal (or tilix) is through Nautilus:

[image]

Since you are able to open terminal and install/remove/upgrade software, upgrade your packages: `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` and reinstall `gnome-terminal` package if previous command did not help:

```
sudo apt purge gnome-terminal* && sudo apt install gnome-terminal gnome-terminal-data
```

Additionally, if you have a Nemo file manager, you could also enable Terminal button displaying on its toolbar in **Edit**->**Preferences**->**Toolbar** making grayed **Open in terminal** button:

[image]
[image]