# Root password typing problem

Tags: password, root

I'm trying to get access to root

I use the command `sudo su-`  and others  for my user and it asks for the passowrd. Then when I type, nothing appears on screen. Then if I press enter, it accepts the empty space as password.

Comment: Related: [Nothing shows up in the terminal when I type my password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/112069/nothing-shows-up-in-the-terminal-when-i-type-my-password)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nothing shows up in the terminal when I type my password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/112069/nothing-shows-up-in-the-terminal-when-i-type-my-password)

Answer (score 3):

It's because things work like this in *nix system.It gives a little bit of extra security by not showing asterisks while you typing because someone seeing your screen might know the length of your password. When the system asks for password, just type and hit enter when finish, things will work if password matches.