# after finishing setup of Ubuntu, upon startup and first command the keyboard input doesn't work

Tags: keyboard, sudo, password, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I finished setting up Ubuntu linux distribution on windows. I setup Ubuntu and created a username and password. Once I thought I was ready to proceed and run my first command, Ubuntu asks for password, but when asked for password my keyboard stops working in the password input box. Any reason why? If I could log in I figure I am all set but this is a weird bug I feel.

Comment: [Nothing shows up in the terminal when I type my password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/112069/nothing-shows-up-in-the-terminal-when-i-type-my-password)

Answer (score 0):

When you are prompted for your password in the terminal and you start typing your password, there will be no visual indication of keystrokes on the display.

This is by design. It's normal and not a bug.  Type your password and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to continue.