# Terminal (cant enter text)

Tags: command-line, sudo, password, cursor

Trying to enter sudo apt clear, or any command for that matter,the response comes asking for my password. I type password and nothing happens. I know that my password is not shown for security, but still after waiting some time, I am unable to enter further text. I run 18.04, and machine runs perfectly other than for using terminal

Comment: Please clarify your details.  `sudo apt clear` should result in an error only, as there is no 'clear' operand for `apt`.  Are you talking about Ubuntu Server, or Desktop.

Comment: Type your password, then press Enter?

Comment: thanks for your response. I think perhaps my message was not concise. If I type a command which request use of my password, The cursor locks and I am unable to enter my password text. I have just inputted "sudo apt-get clean, i am then asked for my password, but the cursor continues to flash with no sign of me being able to complete the action. so, dell@dell-Inspiron-1545:~$ sudo apt-get clean
[sudo] password for dell:

Comment: You say that you *"know the password is not shown for security"*, but what you're describing here does sound exactly like [Nothing shows up in the terminal when I type my password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/112069/nothing-shows-up-in-the-terminal-when-i-type-my-password)

Comment: you press enter after typing your password, and it hangs for a long time (>10s)? have you changed your hostname recently?

Comment: Thank you all for your responses and help. My Laptop is now working perfectly. Taking the advice given and then running Bleachbit completely resolved the problem!

Comment: That's great that you've found a solution!  Can you please post the details of your solution as an answer below so that this question will be helpful to future visitors?