# password . push enter does not help

Tags: password

My password in terminal does not show and when I push enter it says
try again. I have tried 3 versions of my password all with the same result.

Comment: [Nothing shows up in the terminal when I type my password](https://askubuntu.com/a/346424/178692) is the default behavior

Comment: thats a security feature. if you really need to see it, type it out in a text editor, then copy it, 
go to the terminal, press ctrl+shift+v then hit enter.