# Ubuntu 22.04.03 on Sony Vaio tablet

Tags: boot, keyboard, 22.04, tablet, vaio

I have managed to load and run Ubuntu 22.04 on my old Sony Tap 11. However, I have 2 problems:

1. Onscreen keyboard does not come up when logging on- so I have to attach a USB keyboard - not ideal for a tablet
2. Autorotate does not work & cannot find an option/control for it?

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: So, I have found that adding the Accessability menu to the top-right corner system menu option. seems to work. There is aso this option = https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2022/05/enable-on-screen-keyboard-ubuntu-22-04/

Answer (score 0):

So this explins why my password deos not apper in the terminal
[I cannot enter my password in the terminal - can't install packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86660/i-cannot-enter-my-password-in-the-terminal-cant-install-packages)

This solves the screen rotation issue [Rotate touch screen input to match display rotation on Wayland (Ubuntu 22.04)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1419797/rotate-touch-screen-input-to-match-display-rotation-on-wayland-ubuntu-22-04)